# Room - "Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema" - randomly requiring columns to be notNull

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, database-migration

I'm trying to use an upgraded version of my pre-packaged database with `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`. I also just upgraded the Gradle Room version to 2.2.5.

Now first, Room re-created the database wrongly, as it was completely empty. After manually deleting data on the emulator, it pulls the db from assets but I get the schema error.

Using https://hrankit.github.io/RoomSQLiteDifferenceFinder/ I can see that the differences are only in the `notNull` checks of **some** of the columns:

[image].

But I never specified them to be `notNull` in the first place:

```
public class Challenge {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id = 0;

    private final String name;
    @NonNull
    private final ChallengeType type;
    private final String summary;
    @NonNull
    private final String content;
    private final String activePartContent;
    private final String helpContentWhy;
    private final String helpContentHow;
    private final String sources;
    private boolean isActive;
    private int experience;
    private int neededAttempts;

    public Challenge(String name, @NonNull ChallengeType type, String summary, @NonNull String content, String activePartContent, String helpContentWhy, String helpContentHow, String sources, boolean isActive, int experience, int neededAttempts) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.content = content;
        this.activePartContent = activePartContent;
        this.helpContentWhy = helpContentWhy;
        this.helpContentHow = helpContentHow;
        this.sources = sources;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.experience = experience;
        this.neededAttempts = neededAttempts;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @NonNull
    public ChallengeType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public String getActivePartContent() {
        return activePartContent;
    }

    public String getHelpContentWhy() {
        return helpContentWhy;
    }

    public String getHelpContentHow() {
        return helpContentHow;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public String getSources() {
        return sources;
    }

    public int getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    public int getNeededAttempts() {
        return neededAttempts;
    }
}
```

[image]

So whyyyyy is Room bugging me with this. And I don't want to just set these values to `notNull` in my db file because it makes no sense. Might as well have literally everything not Null.

Besides that I remember facing this issue before trying to migrate, when I tried to follow along and set the required fields to notNull, Room would just find another table to complain about notNull. That's why I avoided upgrading the Gradle version number for so long, since it seemed to stem from there.

Comment: Yep, as expected changing these values to true as Room wants it only causes it to jump to another table where it does the same. And there it's literally every single column. I have the suspicion that it does this only for those newly created columns in version 2 of the db, because the table that is new has all columns marked with this.

Comment: Well, after I could not find any other solution, I changed all these random columns to `notNull = true` and it did solve the problem. It mostly seems to have been the integers and booleans for some reason.